# How to create an aws sagemaker project using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sagemaker

This is the terraform shown in the docs:

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_project" "example" {
  project_name = "example"

  service_catalog_provisioning_details {
    product_id = aws_servicecatalog_product.example.id
  }
}
```

I created a service catalog product with id: "prod-xxxxxxxxxxxxx".
When I substitute the service catalog product id into the above template,
to get the following:

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_project" "example" {
  project_name = "example"

  service_catalog_provisioning_details {
    product_id = aws_servicecatalog_product.prod-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  }
}
```

I run terraform plan, but the following error occurs:

```
A managed resource "aws_servicecatalog_product" "prod-xxxxxxxxxxxxx" has not been declared in the root module.
```

What do I need to do to fix this error?

Comment: Do you have that resource defined in the Terraform code? Is this all the Terraform code you have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the documentation is lacking a bit of clarity, in order to have this work as in the example, you would first have to create the Service Catalog product in Terraform as well, e.g.:

```
resource "aws_servicecatalog_product" "example" {
  name  = "example"
  owner = [aws_security_group.example.id] # <---- This would need to be created first
  type  = aws_subnet.main.id # <---- This would need to be created first

  provisioning_artifact_parameters {
    template_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cf-templates-ozkq9d3hgiq2-us-east-1/temp1.json"
  }

  tags = {
    foo = "bar"
  }
}
```

You can reference it then in the SageMaker project the same way as in the example:

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_project" "example" {
  project_name = "example"

  service_catalog_provisioning_details {
    product_id = aws_servicecatalog_product.example.id
  }
}
```

Each of the resources that gets created has a set of attributes that can be accessed as needed by other resources, data sources or outputs. In order to understand how this works, I strongly suggest reading the documentation about referencing values [1]. Since you already created the Service Catalog product, the only thing you need to do is provide the string value for the product ID:

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_project" "example" {
  project_name = "example"

  service_catalog_provisioning_details {
    product_id = "prod-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

When I can't understand what value is expected by an argument (e.g., `product_id` in this case), I usually read the docs and look for examples like in [2]. Note: That example is CloudFormation, but it can help you understand what type of a value is expected (e.g., string, number, bool).

You could also import the created Service Catalog product into Terraform so you can manage it with IaC [3]. You should understand all the implications of `terraform import` though before trying it [4].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references

[2] https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sagemaker-project.html#aws-resource-sagemaker-project--examples--SageMaker_Project_Example

[3] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/servicecatalog_product#import

[4] https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import