# error creating SageMaker project in terraform because service catalog product "does not exist or access was denied"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sagemaker, aws-service-catalog

I have a product with id: prod-xxxxxxxxxxxx. I have checked that it exists in aws service catalog. However, when I try to create an aws_sagemaker_project using terraform:

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_project" "test-project" {
  project_name = "test-project"

  service_catalog_provisioning_details {
    product_id = "prod-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

I get the error: "error creating SageMaker project: ValidationException: Product prod-xxxxxxxxxxxx does not exist or access was denied". How do I ensure that I can access this product?

Do I need a launch constraint for this product, and to grant access to the portfolio to end users as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-projects-templates-custom.html?

Comment: You need quotes around project ID, i.e., `product_id = "prod-xxxxxxxxxxxx"`. You already asked a similar question if I recall correctly and I answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72490682/how-to-create-an-aws-sagemaker-project-using-terraform/72491717#72491717.

Comment: I wasn't very specific in my question. I used quotes around the product id.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you haven't granted access to the service catalog's portfolio to your terraform IAM principal/user/role. Basically you are unable to "see" the product based on the end user section of the service catalog portfolio.

You can fix this by adding the following Servicecatalog resources

```
resource "aws_servicecatalog_principal_portfolio_association" "project" {
  portfolio_id  = aws_servicecatalog_portfolio.portfolio.id
  principal_arn = "${ROLE_ARN}"
}

resource "aws_servicecatalog_portfolio" "portfolio" {
  name          = "My App Portfolio"
  description   = "List of my organizations apps"
  provider_name = "Brett"
}

resource "aws_servicecatalog_product_portfolio_association" "example" {
  portfolio_id = aws_servicecatalog_portfolio.portfolio.id
  product_id   = "prod-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: It is the way to do, confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `aws_servicecatalog_product` terraform state to refer to `product_id`.

```
resource "aws_servicecatalog_product" "example" {
  name  = "example"
  owner = [aws_security_group.example.id]
  type  = aws_subnet.main.id

  provisioning_artifact_parameters {
    template_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cf-templates-ozkq9d3hgiq2-us-east-1/temp1.json"
  }

  tags = {
    foo = "bar"
  }
}

resource "aws_sagemaker_project" "example" {
  project_name = "example"

  service_catalog_provisioning_details {
    product_id = aws_servicecatalog_product.example.id
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I did.